# debug MATLAB mex from gdb via Python API

Tags: matlab, debugging, gdb, mex, gdb-python

I know the process for debugging MATLAB mex files on Linux with gdb, as described here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-linux-platforms.html

This process involves starting MATLAB via command line with

```
 matlab -Dgdb
```

then from gdb console running MATLAB with

```
(gdb) r -nojvm
```

once in gdb, and some other steps to break when a mex is run.

However, I want to do some more advanced wrapping of my gdb debugging via the gdb API for Python.

This process of wrapping gdb API in the Python normally begins with something like the following to debug a program named foo

```
import gdb
gdb.execute('file foo')
gdb.execute('run')
```

I'm not sure if I can apply the same concept to debugging MATLAB. I'm sure its possible, because gdb front-end like gdbgui is built in Python, and can be started up with

```
matlab -Dgdbgui
```

but I'm not sure how to adapt something similar to my own Python wrapper for gdb?

Comment: As it turns out /usr/bin/matlab is just a shell script which wraps the execution of the MATLAB binary. This explains the weird way of invoking MATLAB with -Dgdb for debugging. I'll debug the shell script to find the actual syntax by which MATLAB is called via a debugger, which (in theory) should in turn make it easy to extend via gdb API wrapper in Python

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, I hadn't realized that /usr/bin/matlab is just a shell script, which takes input arguments like -Dgdb and sets up the environment, and runs gdb with the path to the actual MATLAB binary.

My solution was to copy and edit this shell script into /usr/bin/matlab_gdbWrap and comment out the line which actually executes the MATLAB binary:

```
#eval exec "$debugger \"$exec_path\" $arglist"
```

and replace it with the appropriate gdb command to run the Python script with gdb API:

```
eval exec "gdb -x /home/myhome/path/to/gdbWrap.py"
```

In gdbWrap.py I set up my code flow like this:

```
import gdb
import code

# start MATLAB in gdb
gdb.execute('file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB')

 # run MATLAB with -nojvm flag from gdb
gdb.execute('r -nojvm')

# in MATLAB console, run 'dbmex on', and the mex routine, which then breaks out back to gdb, which is in turn controlled by this Python script...

# use Python code module to break out to interactive mode, to begin development of my gdb API wrapper
code.interact(local=locals())
```

The utility of all this may seem to be elusive, but I'm using this to break at certain points in my mex, print the assembly for the next assembly instruction and save it into a Python string variable with

```
gdb.execute('x/i $pc', to_string=True)
```

split that string to get the specific registers used in the following instruction, and print register values, then step, then print register values again. All of this is done with the hopes of debugging the mex at a very low level, by printing the registers from each instruction, before and after each step.